# Github Api v3: When I try to list all the organisation repos I am Getting limited to 30.

Tags: github-api

I would like to list all the repos of the organisation to which I have write access to all the 60 of them. When I try to list the repos by https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/repos its limiting the number of repos to 30, How can I get the access to all the repos in the organisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GitHub API [states](http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination):

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the `?page` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, for Github API, you can set the **per_page** parameter to a larger number (up to **100**). 
Worth noting that not all endpoint respect this parameter, see below explanation:

> Note that for technical reasons not all endpoints respect the ?per_page parameter

You can refer to [this link](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination)